# R: How to plot ONE boxplot from TWO matrices of difference lengths?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, bioinformatics, boxplot

I have 2 matrices. 
The first is something like:

```
[1,] 0.236644700
[2,] 0.194627400
[3,] 0.177236000
[4,] 0.131116300
[5,] 0.103220600
```

The second matrix is:

```
[1,] 3.722219e-01
[2,] 3.212364e-01
[3,] 3.112315e-01
[4,] 3.078721e-01
[5,] 3.023402e-01
[6,] 2.979626e-01
[7,] 2.939100e-01
[8,] 2.860793e-01
[9,] 2.790241e-01
[10,] 2.778401e-01
```

Both matrices are actually a lot bigger than they're here. I want to get a single boxplot for these two matrices. So there'd be two boxes side by side on one boxplot. I also have a vector named z that contains the names for these boxes where:

```
z=c("SNP", "CNV")
```

and I also want to plot z on the boxplot to label the boxes. I tried using the boxplot-matrix() function but it didn't work since these are matrices of different length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as `boxplot(m1, m2, names=z)`.